# Parent module use Child run()

Tags: angularjs

I try to declare a `main` module, to manage sub module component.

When I create a `run()` method in my sub module, my parent uses it.

I need to execute a specific modification only for my sub module.

Isn't it the usable case for `run()` ?

```
angular.module('app', ['sub'])
    .run(function ($http) {
       console.log("run main");
    })
angular.module('sub',[]).
   .run(function ($http) {
       console.log("run sub");
   });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/HpD7y/

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. If you want to change the way something works on a page you can inject different services into a controller and call the appropriate routine on that service. As a rule - I haven't seen very many cases when you need to modules. Maybe you could explain the question further?

Comment: I need to create main module, to manage independant each other sub module. Not sure it's the best way to do that...

Comment: I finally found another way to do what I need.
I declare my modules like sibling, so my maid module don't use run of his child.

Comment: I'm glad you found a pattern that works for you. You might consider posting it here if you think it would help others in the future. If you do this you may also get useful feedback on the code you have written. Just a thought!

Answer (score 0):

I finally change the dependencies between my modules.

### To provide more informations

My `main` module have global factory, and some directives.

My sub modules need use global factory, and other behavior declared in `main`.
I'll need to do some check when he was "instanciate" : `run()`

### Problem

When i create my `main` module, he use the `run()` (same thing for configuration of `$httpProvider`)  of his sub module.

### Solution

I've simply create my sub module like **sibling**, and create a specific module for my global factory.

### Exemple

```
angular.module('app', ['globalFactories'])
   .run(function(){
       console.log("app"); 
   });

angular.module('sub', ['globalFactories'])
   .run(function(){
       console.log("sub"); 
    });


angular.module('globalFactories', [])
    .factory('context', function ($http) {
        var url = '/api/context/';
        return {
            createContext: function(item){
                 return $http.post(url, item);
            }
        }
    });
```